# Forwarding requests made to Windows DNS server for a domain it's authoritative for but doesn't have a record matching the request, onto BIND?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dynamic-dns, windows-dns

Is it possible on a Windows DNS server to have it forward/proxy requests for a domain it's authoritative for but doesn't have a record matching the request.. onto another server like a BIND server ?

Most records for this domain are managed by Windows and BIND will have a smaller number of records that are dynamically registered/updated/deleted with nsupdate from Linux servers. This is for private cloud testing project we're doing and i want them to be able to easy register/update their info in DNS via nsupdate.

Thanks
fLo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with delegation. It's easier if all the remote records are under a single sub-domain, like let's say you have `cloud.domain.com` and your BIND server has a zone matching that.

In Windows DNS, create a sub-domain (right click the zone, click **New Domain...**), call it `cloud`. That looks like a sub-folder.

Within there, create `NS` records that point to your BIND server.

All queries for that sub-domain should then go to that DNS server.

If the records are all going to be direct descendants of domain.com, then you do the same thing, it's just more tedious because you have to keep creating sub-domains for each individual record.

See [Understanding Zone Delegation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771640.aspx) for a nice diagram and more information.

Comment: thanks for info, creating a new subdomain to hold all BIND hosted records and delegating that from within Windows to the BIND nameserver makes sense. I was trying to do this, as you said with the records being direct descendants of domain.com. But having to manually add a delegation per record would defeat the point of automating record CRUD with nsupdate/BIND. Unless anyone comes up with a better magic trick to let windows pass through lookups to BIND, I'll accept this answer in couple days.

Comment: Yeah making a single subdomain is a much better option going forward if you have that option. Also note that if you accept/vote up an answer, you can change it at any time if something better comes along. :)